# What is the plant on the RIGHT?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care

That's pretty much it. I need to care for this unknown plant. What is it?

[image]

Comment: The picture is so dark its hard to see detail - the leaves to the left o the plant you;re asking about look as if they have white spots on them, but can you post a better lit one please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phlebodium aureum, AKA Blue Star Fern.  Like most ferns they want moist, not wet, soil at all times.  When the top of the soil becomes dry down to the second knuckle of your index finger it is time to water again.   Water until water comes out the bottom of the pot, then stop.  Dump out any excess water out of the catch basin.  It is best to give this plant some additional humidity.  You can do this by putting stones in the catch basin and place the plant on top of the stones.  In this case you can leave the water in the basin as long as the water does not pass the stones.  Keep the plant in a shaded area of your room, but not a dark corner.  Fertilise three times during the growing season, from May until August.

[Phlebodium aureum](https://houseplantcentral.com/phlebodium-aureum-blue-star-fern-care/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a fern. that's a start for ID